# Establishing relationships automatically

Tags: trigger, lookup, relationships

I have a record with a code field and I have custom metadata which maps from code to textual description. I would like my users to be able to see in the layouts and reports not only the code but the textual relationship too.

Typically when I insert via API I only have the code and I have to write custom trigger to establish the lookup relationship. Is there a better way? Can this code be auto-generated with some packages or at least replaced by a process on process builder?

Comment: Is the code unique in the lookup? If so make if and external  id and when you create the record you can populate the lookup using the code as the external in the foreign key

Comment: It is unique and I did the test via code and it works if I create an object with that External Id. I.e. myObj.MyRelation = new MyRelation ( externalId = 'bla'). Via SOAP API though I am not sure how this should be done?